# How to Block a GitHub PR Merge Programmatically

Tags: github, github-api, slack, slack-api, github-actions

I'd like to have an external event (Slack message or queue event) block a merge on GitHub (turn the big green button red/gray). This is possible now through web hooks after CI has run in Jenkins/GitLab/Actions or if a reviewer asks for changes.

One of the workflows for the project I'm on is to request reviews from Slack and putting "eyes" emojis on the Slack post signifies to the code author that someone is in the middle of a review. I want to write a Slack bot to look for these eye emojis and put a block on the associated PR merge. Then after the reviews are complete when the "eyes" are removed, release the PR.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote this question, I realized I could have Slack post to the GitHub PR with "Request Changes", thereby blocking the merge. Chattier than I'd like on the PR page but has the advantage of having review start events captured in the email chain (which are easily filtered if desired).